# Java Countdown ends without returning into the main

Tags: java, timer, countdown

I've got a program that controls an electronic component. My problem is the part with the countdown. Practically if I call the class CountDown from the main method, it won't return to the main. The program must be always active and it reads the first value in the main for call and start the countdown.
This is the code:

```
public class CountDown
{
    public static int a;
    public static Timer timer;

    public CountDown()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new DisplayCountdown(), 0, 1000);
    }

    class DisplayCountdown extends TimerTask
    {
        int seconds = 15;
        public void run()
        {
            if (seconds > 0)
            {
                System.out.println(seconds + " seconds remaining");

                if(READING BY ELECTRONIC COMPONENT == 1)
                {
                    seconds=15;
                } else {
                    seconds--;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Countdown finished");
                CountDown.a=0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        CountDown.a = 0;

        while(true)
                {
         if(READING ELECTRONIC COMPONENT == 1)
         {
            if (CountDown.a==0)
            {
                CountDown.a = 1;
                new CountDown();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not proper usage of a `TimerTask`. They're intended to allow things to occur in the background while your software does other things (you're just scheduling some code to be executed), so of course it won't wait until the countdown is done then return to main. What are you actually trying to achieve with this? It would be easier to suggest an alternate approach if we know what the goal is.

Comment: I have a sensor and an electronic component, when the sensor value is 1 it starts the countdown that resets each time it detects a movement. When the sensor is 0 and the countdown ends it should continue to monitor the sensor with the main if. Thanks!

Comment: @Kerberos: Are you shure that the main method will be called? Tell me if I'm wrong, but I think you start a loop by calling the inner class in the construtor.

Comment: @reporter: Maybe you're right! But I can't test it because I've everything in the lab! If it's right, how I can call first the main? Thanks for all.

Comment: @reporter Nothing is causing the constructor to be executed before the `new CountDown()` line in the main method (at least not in the code displayed). Executing static methods (like main) doesn't require an instance to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked to make sure my suspicions are correct. It's not that your `new Countdown()` isn't returning to the main method, it's that it returns *immediately*. What you want is likely to do some kind of waiting in the `while(true)` loop and checking whether or not the countdown is completed. Something along the lines of:

```
CountDown countDown = null;
while(true)
{
    if (countDown == null || getReading() == 1)
    {
        if (CountDown.a == 0)
        {
            CountDown.a = 1;
            countDown = new CountDown();
        }
    }
    while (countDown.isRunning())
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(countDown.getRemainingSeconds() * 1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            // Ignore.
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to implement the isRunning and getRemainingSeconds methods (you could always sleep for a set amount rather than trying to wait exactly the right amount of time if you want).

I'd also recommend trying to make this class better suited for re-use by avoiding the static variables `a` and `timer` (use private variables and setters/initialise them in the constructor instead).